# Does Apache Thrift allow foreign function calls between any two languages?

Tags: language-agnostic, thrift

I'm currently trying to develop (an API in multiple programming languages) that can be accessed from (various other programming languages). I've taken a look at Apache Thrift, and it appears that it might be possible to allow seamless foreign function calls between any two languages using Thrift. Is this correct?

Comment: Brackets above added for clarity (to resolve the confusing semantics of the first sentence.)

Comment: Also, I'm interested in learning how to use Apache Thrift to invoke foreign functions (from one Thrift-supported language to another Thrift-supported language.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thrift is created to facilitate communication between different processes over the network, not in process FFI. It is probably possible to take some parts of Thrift (like IDL), and adopt it for FFI, but it could be an nontrivial undertaking, and provide suboptimal results.

Comment: In that case, are there any other software frameworks that would be more suitable for cross-language FFI?

Comment: Also, I don't completely understand the difference between RPC (remote procedure calling) and FFI. What's the main difference?

Comment: RPC calls function in another process usually on different machine. To do so on the caller side or parameters are serialized into the byte stream, and that byte stream is then transferred over the network, or some other inter process communication to the implementor of the function. He in turn deserializes byte stream received, and creates all data structuctures necessary to invoke function in process that implements function, and then function gets called. Similar process goes on when function returns value but in othe direction. This is what thrift does.

Comment: in FFI on the other hand both caller and function live in the same process, and all serialization/deserialization is not necessary, and does not take place. There may be some massaging of parameters if languages are to different, but still in much simpler way than RPC serialization/deserialization.

Comment: It is of course a trivial undertaking. You use only the serialization part, you don't need the RPC part.

Answer (score 1):

I have actually been thinking of something similar myself.

There are core concepts to the Thrift specification.

- The Transport: This portion is responsible for facilitating data transfer between a client and server.
- The Protocol: This portion is responsible for formatting the said data in different ways. It can be a JSON,  compressed binary, even raw uncompressed binary.
- The Server: This is responsible for putting these things together and managing them.

Thrift allows you to mix these different parts in unique ways to create something suitable to your purpose. Thrift is still very much server-client oriented though.

To develop an API in thrift would mean that you could theoreticallly have plugins in any language. The main software component would launch the sub-process and use STD-IN/OUT as a Transport. This would allow it to make RPC calls regardless of Language.