# Running Apache Thrift in a single process / as a foreign function interface

Tags: thrift, ffi

Apache Thrift provides traditional RPC, with distinct client and server processes.
Is it possible to use it as a foreign function interface?
Here, a single thread's call stack could contain both client and server code.

EDIT: This question was basically asked a year ago:
[Does Apache Thrift allow foreign function calls between any two languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887932/does-apache-thrift-allow-foreign-function-calls-between-any-two-languages)
Any updates?
It seems like all the pieces are already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Let me turn the question around: **What exactly makes you think, that this should not be possible?**

Of course you can combine any combination of server and client within one module, process, multiple processes or machines. The location of server and client end do not matter as long as they are able to communicate. Even if "server" and "client" (better terms would be caller and callee) are located within the same thread - you just use the serialization part in that case.

Do you have any particular problems, any piece of code you might want to share that is not working as expected?

---

Short sketch/idea how it could work:

```
- outer code
  - setup a service client using stream transport
  - call service client's xxx-send() function 
  - pass stream/string data to inner module via dedicated function call
    - create processor instance
    - pass stream data as input, provide another stream for output data
      - call to inner code
    - return output stream/string data to outer module
  - setup a service client using stream transport
  - call service client's xxx-recv() function 
  - return the data
```

I have already used approx. 75% of the pieces outlined above with Delphi and C# and I'm positive that the rest could work out as well (the swiss army knife again). Can't say much about how the Python code supports that today, or what needs to be done to achieve that with Python.

The easier way would be as follows (note there is no interface at all):

```
- outer code
  - setup a service client using stream transport
  - serialize args structure (e.g. union, to support different calls)
  - pass stream/string data to inner module via dedicated function call
    - deserialize args
      - call to inner code
    - serialize output struct (again, union to ...)
    - return stream/string to outer module
  - deserialize the data
  - return the data
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my question. Indeed I believe it should be possible, but I haven't seen any mention of anyone using Thrift in this way. If Thrift can be used this way, I'd like an example. If it can't, I'd like a reason.

Comment: I haven't either. Maybe it's just not a "mainstream" use case.

Comment: Again, since we are on SO here, some piece of (pseudo?) code to talk about would be a better start than such a merely vague and conceptual question.  -  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic